# Font not found issue

Tags: fonts, luatex

I uploaded the zip folder provided by the organising committee of a conference on overleaf. Here is the error message

[image]

Compiler I used :LuaLa Tex

So I manually uploaded the regular `cambria.ttf` file from the internet. For some reason the font is slightly different from the word doc version provided by the committee.
Is the error due to a missing font file for which I need to reach out to the organising committee or can it be solved otherwise?

Comment: it should be `\setmathfont{Cambriamath}`, and the font you need is then `cambria.ttc`

Comment: as Ulrike says, but also it's unlikely that you have a licence that allows uploading Cambria